# TypeError: unhashable type 'ObjectAssociationProxyInstance' when running async select query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am writing a simple Task crud api using FastAPI and sqlalchemy. I've been converting the code to run asynchronously, but have run into problems with the sqlalchemy `select` api. I use [Generic association tables](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.html) to store comments related to different Task models.

My queries are of the form `query = select(models.Task).where(models.Task.id == id).options(selectinload(Task.comments))`. I then execute the query with `result = await db.execute(query)` where `db`is an `AsyncSession`instance.

This results in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'ObjectAssociationProxyInstance'`. Am I building the query wrong? My understanding of the generic association table is that placing a backref on the association table is sufficient to access the relationship directly from the parent table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on my end and asked the same question in the SQLAlchemy Github Discussion.

It turns out that `selectinload()` does not support targets that are association proxies.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9345